# JNI: EnsureLocalCapacity ignored

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

i invoke EnsureLocalCapacity() in every native method call in the very beginning:

```
void ensureMemory(JNIEnv *env) {
    jint ensureResult = env->EnsureLocalCapacity(MAX_LOCALS_COUNT);
    debug("ensure result for %i is %i", MAX_LOCALS_COUNT, ensureResult);
```

> ensure result for 1024 is 0
>
> env: [0x7fccc60011d0]

and it crashes after few invocations on `env->NewObject()` (exception is hijacked by clang (which i try to use via clang c-api)):

> libclang: crash detected during indexing source file: {
>   'source_filename' :
>   '/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/clang_jni/mac/test/TestFile.h'
>   'command_line_args' : ['-c', '-x', 'c++'],   'unsaved_files' : [],
>   'options' : 0, }

So it seems to be 16 local refs limit exceeded though i call `env->DeleteLocalRef` every time i don't need local var. What should i do?

Comment: 1024 is an awful lot of locals. If you're calling `DeleteLocalRef()` surely you don't really need 1024? I use `Push/PopLocalFrame()`, easier to manage than deleting things manually.

Comment: i'm parsing source code into tokens and it can have a lot of tokens so  i try to allocate as lot local refs as i can though i do DeleteLocalRef every time i finish with a ref.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with calling `EnsureLocalCapacity` in JNI_OnLoad()